# How to remove text from a line after "." in awk?

Tags: awk

I have found a few answers to similar questions where the author wants to remove text after a certain character in a string ([example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117384/how-can-i-remove-the-text-from-a-line-after-a-certain-character-with-awk)). I would like to do a similar thing, however, the character I wish to use is `"."`, specifically when there are three occurrences e.g. `"..."`. Whenever I use the commands I have found, all of the characters are removed.

Example input file:  InFile.txt:

```
GCA_000260195.2_FO_II5_V1_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_11158-16380_64... *
GCA_000350365.1_Foc4_1.0_B2_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_73046-78268_63... at 100.00%
GCA_001696625.1_C1HIR_9889_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_338336-343558_32... at 100.00%
GCA_007994515.1_UK0001_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_482256-487478_64... at 100.00%
GWHAASU00000000_FocTR4_58.genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_429502-434724_64... at 100.00%
```

Example command 1: `awk -F'...' '{print $1}' InFile.txt`

Output of Example command 1 is just blank space.

I have tried putting the characters in "" e.g.

```
Example command 2: awk -F'"..."' '{print $1}' InFile.txt
```

Which produces this output:

```
GCA_000260195.2_FO_II5_V1_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_11158-16380_64... *
GCA_000350365.1_Foc4_1.0_B2_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_73046-78268_63... at 100.00%
GCA_001696625.1_C1HIR_9889_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_338336-343558_32... at 100.00%
GCA_007994515.1_UK0001_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_482256-487478_64... at 100.00%
GWHAASU00000000_FocTR4_58.genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_429502-434724_64... at 100.00%
```

Ideally, I'd like the output to look like this:

```
GCA_000260195.2_FO_II5_V1_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_11158-16380_64
GCA_000350365.1_Foc4_1.0_B2_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_73046-78268_63
GCA_001696625.1_C1HIR_9889_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_338336-343558_32
GCA_007994515.1_UK0001_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_482256-487478_64
GWHAASU00000000_FocTR4_58.genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_429502-434724_64
```

How do I remove text after "..." without replacing all of the text?

Thanks,
Jamie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try following, you need to escape it to tell `awk` to treat `.` as a literal character.

```
awk -F'\\.\\.\\.' '{print $1}' Input_file
```

OR as per Sundeep sir's comments use:

```
awk -F'\\.{3}' '{print $1}' Input_file
```

***Correcting OP's attempt:*** Also you need NOT to use field separator as `-F'"..."'` we need not to use `"` here, instead use only `-F'your_delimiter'`.

***Bonus solution:*** In case one doesn't want to use field separator then use `sub` here.

```
awk '{sub(/\.\.\..*/,"")} 1' Input_file
```

Comment: can also use `-F'\\.{3}'` or `-F'[.]{3}'`

Answer (score 3):

[Answer from @RavinderSingh13](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63919048/548225) is great as it shows how to properly handle regex meta characters in `FS`.

Here is an alternate `awk` that doesn't use any regex and hence doesn't need any escaping:

```
awk '{print substr($0, 1, index($0, "...") - 1)}' file
```

```
GCA_000260195.2_FO_II5_V1_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_11158-16380_64
GCA_000350365.1_Foc4_1.0_B2_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_73046-78268_63
GCA_001696625.1_C1HIR_9889_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_338336-343558_32
GCA_007994515.1_UK0001_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_482256-487478_64
GWHAASU00000000_FocTR4_58.genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_429502-434724_64
```